# Automatically Update Page Numbers for Table of Contents in DOCX generated using OpenXML SDK

Tags: ms-word, openxml-sdk, tableofcontents, page-numbering

I have been able to successfully generate word document (.docx) using OpenXML SDK 2.5.

Can we directly update the page numbers in TOC of the generated document using OpenXML SDK
I found few similar queries on Stack overflow.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348550/how-to-generate-table-of-contents-using-openxml-sdk-2-5]

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762684/how-to-generate-table-of-contents-using-openxml-sdk-2-0/]

One of the ways is to have users click yes to update the Table of Contents on a modal dialog when they  open the document the first time. Is there a way to avoid this modal dialog and user intervention but still update page numbers on opening the document the first time?

Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the page numbers can be different depending on how the opening application renders the document, i don't think that there is a way to do that by means of the OpenXml-SDK.

You can update fields/tocs using a macro or automation:
[How to automatically update tables of contents](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2007/how-to-automatically-update-tables-of-contents/626dabcd-cdc4-4780-a979-82d1a6faefda)

Comment: I don't want to use automation. And for using a macro I need to have a Macro enabled document with extension docm'. How do I do this in a docx file.

Comment: In this case, if you do not want to render the document yourself, i suppose using some third-party (i.e. Aspose) tool to get the rendering done. Maybe there will be a license fee.